# wrong data in fields

Tags: java, swing

This is fragment of class in my program (I deleted some not important code). At First, program always calls method `firstSet()` which sets all JLabels(players) on JPanel(board). Then when I click on JLabel, `mouseClicked()` runs method `findPlayer()`, so I know which JLabel whose chose. To this moment everything is OK.

Problem begins when I start simulation - method `simulationStart()` run 10 times. After this when I click player, cmd line shows: `I can't find it :(`. I wrote some system.out to find out what is wrong. Problem is in fields `locationX` and `locationY`, I don't know why they are different in `findPlayer()` and `simulationStart()`.

```
public class setBoard extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    int[] locationX = new int[100];
    int[] locationY = new int[100];

    public void setLocation() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            locationX[i] = (int) (random() * (sizeX - xy));
            locationY[i] = (int) (random() * (sizeY - xy));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<JLabel> firstSet() {
        setLocation();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            player = new JLabel();

            //
            //some code to JLabel set
            //

            playerList.add(player);
            player.setBounds(locationX[i], locationY[i]);
            player.addMouseListener(this);
        }

        return playerList;
    }

    public ArrayList<JLabel> simulationStart(ArrayList<JLabel> playerList) {
        this.playerList = playerList;

        setLocation();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            playerList.get(i).setBounds(locationX[i], locationY[i]);
            playerList.add(playerList.get(i));
        }
        return playerList;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {     
        //
        //a lot of code to  search coursorX and coursorY, this works good
        //

        //if left mouse button 
        if (e.getButton() == 1) {
            final int playerNr = findPlayer(coursorX, coursorY);
            if (playerNr == -1) {
                System.out.println("I can`t find it :( ");
            }
            else{
                //
                //code to do when it find player
                //
            }
        }
    }

    //
    //
    //

    private int findPlayer(int x, int y) {
        int playerNr = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (x == locationX[i] && y == locationY[i]) {
                playerNr = i;
            }
        }
        return playerNr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your approach seems unnecessarily complicated - you should be able to just call `e.getSource()` to find out which player was clicked on. Or maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jzd - you are understand what I`m doing, but maybe I don`t understand getSource() method :) When I call it in system.out for random player, I have something like this: javax.swing.JLabel[,93,7,10x10,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0 ......, so 93 is is coursorX, and 7 is coursorY. This is exactly what I`m doing in code in comment //a lot of code to  search coursorX and coursorY. Then I must find out which player is this, so I call findPlayer(coursorX, coursorY), to compare my last setted location with current mouse click.

Comment: I think you meant to comment to Robin, not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `simulationStart` you are adding players to the playerList again. So the number of players goes above 100. Why don't you try printing out the size of playerList and check if it is what you expect?

I think you may need to remove the statement: `playerList.add(playerList.get(i));`

Comment: you are right, I deleted this line, but it steel doesn't work

Comment: OK OK,
Thank you for help. I solve problem by adding name to JLabel. Now I can find my player by name and I don't have to search location :)